# Calculate height of div and place that number in ::after pseudo element content

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to display the actual height of a div using a pseudo element.

The main idea in css would be:

`div:before {content:"the height of this container is X pixels tall";}`

X would be calculated somehow using css or jquery-? This text will be displayed next to the div.

Comment: how is the rest of code ? (html, css) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way ?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.SizDiv').forEach(xDiv=>{
  xDiv.dataset.info = `_height=${xDiv.offsetHeight}px_`
})

/* first proposal:
const myDiv = document.querySelector('#my-Div')
myDiv.dataset.info = `the height of this container is ${myDiv.offsetHeight} pixels tall `
*/
```

```css
.SizDiv {
  width           : 300px;
  background-color: orangered;
  margin          : 10px;
}

.SizDiv:before {
   content   : attr(data-info);
   color     : darkblue;
   font-size : 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="SizDiv" data-info="" >
  <br> B<br> C<br> D<br> E<br> F<br> G<br> H
</div>

<div class="SizDiv" data-info="" >
  <br> B<br> C<br> D<br> G<br> J
</div>

<div class="SizDiv" data-info="" >
 <br> B<br> C<br> K
</div>
```

this code refer to:
[HTML data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)
[CSS content (::before/after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)
[Javascript dataset (for html data attributes)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset)

Comment: Y E S !   I wish I had another lifetime to learn javascript. Thank you!

Comment: Would there be a way to do this without the data-info="something" being added to the html?

Comment: @tlrichman no, [to my knowledge,] I do not think there is any other way than using one of the attributes of the parent

Comment: Is it possible to use a class instead of an id? The goal being to use this on multiple divs…

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much.